# Internet based application

Tags: vb.net

I have developed some software(vb.net) that records fees paid by the students.  The purpose is that the database should be stored in a server, which can be accessed from any stations linked with it.

This is working fine with a network of 10 computers.  I need to publish it over the net so
people could do this job logging in over internet.  Database (access database) should be stored on a web based server.

How is this possible?  Even little help shall be highly appreciated.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

First option you build a web application and fill your information into an access file. But using access as database is very dangerous and I can't recommend using access.

Second option you build a client application which connects to a database which is running on a central server. This won't work with access at least not very well. So again my advice is that you should use sql express version which is free. You connect to the database with your connectionstring.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am very new to vb.net
Please advise me how to convert my existing application's database sql server database?
Also, what will be the connection string?
Do you know any free sites that could give me hosting space, just as an experiment?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: If you have no knowledge at all you should start reading a book like that one (free):
http://www.ebook3000.com/Database-Programming-with-VB-NET-and-ADO-NET_1325.html

A connectionstring determines where your database is running so on which machine and with which credentials see connectionstrings.com

You don't need a free hosting to test because you can use sqlexpress locally on your machine. After the application is running without errors you can move your database and application.

You can use sql server with ms sql express management studio. This should make it easier for you.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot for the help.  I tried the link but content removed from this site.
Can you suggest anything else?
Thanks / Furqan

Comment: Hey Furqan,
there are plenty of books on books.google.com. Try this one:

http://books.google.de/books?id=BDVer_T3TcMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Database+Programming+with+VB.NET+and+ADO.NET&hl=de&ei=fiZpTJr2BMjKjAf-9pDVBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Database%20Programming%20with%20VB.NET%20and%20ADO.NET&f=false