# ASP.Net applications

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between vb.net application and asp.net application?
How can I publish an ASP.Net application with database residing in the server and user could update that through internet?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate or rewording by same person of [Internet based application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450408/internet-based-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET is a language and ASP.NET is a web technology.
Refer to links below to learn and understand them

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-getting-started

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/

http://www.codefixer.com/asp-net/tutorials/

And database will be on server, you need to access it in your asp.net application using connection string. You can set it up in web.config

Refer this for different syntax 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

To learn more on how to work with databases using asp.net/.net applications
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple: ASP.NET applications are web applications that can be written in VB.NET.

Comment: OK, thanks but is syntex the same as vb.net?
Where does database go?

Comment: Like rs said, "VB.NET is a language and ASP.NET is a web technology". ASP.NET does not have a syntax of its own.  ASP.NET applications are usually developed in VB.NET or C#.  In other words, you can use VB.NET to create an ASP.NET web application.